# Subversion commit problem

Tags: svn, netbeans

Hi
I have a problem in committing my changes to SVN.
I get the message:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   Illegal repository URL ''

I'm using netbeans.

Any help please ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think: what's CVN? You're not confusing CVS and SVN (= subversion)?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your repository URL is incorrect. Check to be sure that your repository is pointing to the right place;

```
$ svn info
Path: .
URL: https://... ** is this right?
Repository Root: https://... ** Is this right?
<snip>
```

If that's correct, is your SVN server running? Can you ping the server, verify that SVN is running, etc.?

Comment: Maybe not so much "bad" but more rather "inconsistent."

This problem can happen if you've checked out different subdirectories of the repo with different-but-equivalent URLs.  For instance specifying http one time and https another.  Then trying to check them in all at once gives the error.  Fix like this:

$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/http:/https:/;' */.svn/entries

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error, and the issue turned out to be that I was trying to commit both local changes and changes to external projects - as described here [How do I checkin to local copy AND svn:externals subdirectories in one commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336790/how-do-i-checkin-to-local-copy-and-svnexternals-subdirectories-in-one-commit).

Comment: This helped me, although I have no idea if there are external things in the project I'm working with. I just committed everything separatedly (each subfolder or file) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `svn switch CORRECT_URL`

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is correct, then it might be a proxy issue. For example if you are behind a corporate firewall, then you have to set up the proxy server as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes directories get checked out under aliases.  I had a situation where most files were checked out using the URL svn://server.company.com/repo but one was checked out under svn://server/repo and Subversion got confused, throwing this error when I tried to check files in under both directories simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in TortoiseSVN and it was actually because of the hidden folder that stores all the .svn files. These files contain some pointers that can get messed up if you're copying and pasting files.

I had copied an entire folder from TestBoxA to TextBoxB and thusly accidentally dragged the hidden .svn files with it. Since all the .svn files were still pointing to TestBoxA, I got that error.

The simple fix was to enable File Explorer-> View -> Show Hidden Folders so I could see hidden folders and delete the folder named "svn" in the corrupted folder. SVN generated new .svn files when I committed.